# How to get ansi color output in windows powershell?

Tags: windows, ansi-colors

When Jenkins runs in Windows powershell, I get the following output
â“˜  browser name internet explorer

I think its because Windows does not support ansi color output. Is it possible to have Windows powershell support ansi?